# indic-text-renderer using harfbuzz and freetype

Tags: android, fonts, android-ndk, indic, harfbuzz

I am developing an Android application which should support Devanagari Fonts. So I downloaded [indic-text-renderer](https://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/) and tried to run it as per the instruction stated [here](https://code.google.com/p/indic-text-renderer/source/browse/HowToBuild.txt) and managed to successfully compile the NDK part.

But when I try to run the Android project on a gingerbread emulator I get following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:    33 cannot locate 'hb_buffer_create'...
```

I tried many solution but none of them helped me.

How can I fix this?

Has anyone used indic-text-renderer in Android successfully?

If yes, please help me and provide a complete Android project (if possible) as I am trying to install and compile this library. It needs to make, javah, autoconfig and many more...

Comment: Were you about to get it to work? If so, do you have a link to your complete Android project? I also have a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539237/supporting-complex-text-layout-with-opentype-fonts-in-android

Comment: Nope. I tried a lot but no luck,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I managed to solve it by statically link harfbuzz to my ndk library. So try to statically link harfbuzz to your ndk lib.
e.g. in CMake:

```
add_library(harfbuzz SHARED ...)
```

to

```
add_library(harfbuzz STATIC ...)
```